# CodeIgniter URL rewrite - but not on the XAMPP directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I'd like to take out the `index.php` from all of the pages served by CodeIgniter - but I want to still be able to access everything inside my XAMPP folder as normal.

This is my directory structure :

```
htdocs\
.\Application\
.\XAMPP\
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

So, I'd like to be able to see my application as `http:\\localhost\controller\method\arg` instead of `http:\\localhost\index.php\controller\method\arg`.

But I also want to be able to see `http:\\localhost\XAMPP\index.php` - XAMPP has my control panel in it like MySQL and I can't get to it with my `.htaccess` file in place (because it rewrites to `http:\\localhost\XAMPP\` and not `http:\\localhost\XAMPP\index.php` ) .

Is this possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand your question just put an .htaccess file into XAMPP directory with the directive `RewriteEngine off`. It should work